# Eiffel: What's the difference between an "eiffel" library and a gobo library?

Tags: eiffel

Eiffel: What's the difference between an "eiffel" library and a gobo library? for example with xml, which should I choose and why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially EiffelSoftware XML library was built an alternative/replacement for Gobo XML, because Gobo was not Void-safe at that time.
Also, Eiffel XML does not depend on the Gobo package (many good Eiffel libraries, that uses their own structures, own files interfaces and so on). 
Eiffel XML is based on EiffelBase, and does not bring all the Gobo dependencies.

Note also, Gobo XML callbacks are using STRING, and variants of UC_STRING, while Eiffel XML uses directly STRING_32.
Eiffel XML supports only ASCII, and UTF-8 encoding, while Gobo XML has stronger encoding support via the descendants of UC_STRING.
Gobo XML is may be more complete (but this needs to be checked).

So the choice really depends on your needs.
If your application is already using Gobo structures, then you should probably use Gobo XML.
Otherwise I would suggest to use Eiffel XML (unless Eiffel XML does not support the encoding you care about).

Comment: Thx!, could you provide a brief description of what is `gobo` and `EiffelSoftware library`